# Need a definition

Tags: translation, german-to-english

My family seems to have inherited a word from our parents and grandparents that we cannot define.  Might be spelled Losch (with e umlaut).  Best I can find is that that root meaning is something that needs cleaning or clearing.  I found many compounds that seemed to be about cleaning things.  Any ideas about what the word might be and its accurate definition?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would use it in context? i.e. The Lösch tastes great.

Comment: (Feuer) löschen - to put out; to extinguish (fire) ? It could also be "durst löschen" the result of that is to not be thirsty anymore. Context might really be helpful,..

Comment: My first idea was [Löschpapier](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Löschpapier)  - maybe it's related to this.

Comment: What do you mean by "with e umlaut"? Do you mean "with o umlaut"? The later would be ö as in Lösch(en), the first would be ë, which is very rarely used in the spelling of foreign names such as Alëuten.

Comment: Your description is not enough to pin down exactly what word you are looking for. Can you give a bit more context? When do you use this word? Is it a noun or a verb or something else?

Comment: BTW, there is no "E umlaut", at least not in German, and strictly speaking not in English either, unless you just consider trema, diaeresis & umlaut synonyms. The two dots on an E are usually called _trema_.

Comment: Please provide a **context** to get this question reopened. Thank you.

Comment: could be "Loch" too... a dirty flat is often called a "Loch"... but without an example it is impossible to tell.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the word you want is lösen. That means "to solve." As in to solve a problem.

It can also refer to "cleaning," as a cleaner is otherwise known as a "solvent."

Comment: Seriously? How did you infer from "Losch (with e umlaut)", which looks like a noun to me, that the OP is looking for the verb "lösen"?

Comment: @Earthling: Because OP also mentioned "the root meaning is something [a noun] that needs cleaning or clearing. I found many compounds that seemed to be about cleaning." The verb "lösen" is about solving, dissolving, undoing, cleaning, etc. If you want a noun form, it's Lösung.

Comment: But it doesn't have an SCH.

Comment: @Earthling: OP said, "MIGHT BE spelled" (with an sch). He's guessing, by his own admission. So my guess is as good as his. Put another way, I emphasized the REST of his post, that is the definition, rather than the spelling.

Comment: Fine. You answered my question "How did you infer...?". I guess someone should post all the other words that start with L and mean something like "clearing, cleaning" and the OP can pick his favourite as answer.